# inotifywait don't have access to folder

Tags: command-line, permissions, directory

I got a problem with my folder rights/groups settings.

One folder does have 755 and a group 'xyz'. I am in that group 'xyz' and I can actually see it's contents when I list it on terminal.

By running the following inotifywait-command from my user account I expect that command would have the same rights?

```
inotifywait -m -q -e create /home/aerofs/ | while read f;do echo "created";done
```

It doesn't show 'create'. When I use an another folder with my group in it ... then it does work.

Can someone help me out here?

Thanks...

Comment: What is the exact command? You're not actually using `[FOLDER]` are you? I ask because `[ ]` are special characters so your example is confusing. Please [edit] and clarify and also provide an example showing the exact permissions where it works and those where it fails.

Comment: No, [FOLDER] is just an example for placeholder.

Comment: OK, but please [edit] your question and show us the exact permissions of the working and non working directories. You said in a comment below that you don't actually have `755` but `775`. Please [edit] and correct the typo as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want everyone in the group 'xyz' to have write permissions to that directory, you need to change the permissions to 775 instead of 755. 755 will allow users within group 'xyz' to read and execute the directory but not write to it.

Run the following command to fix this:

```
chmod 775 /path/to/folder
```

More reference on file and directory permissions:

[linux.com - Understanding Linux File Permissions](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions)

...also:

[Ubuntu Community Help Wiki - FilePermissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions)

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake in my text. I do have 775.

Comment: Maybe it could be that I started a command/script which does not have the same rights as I do?

Comment: I found it. The notify command doesn't recognize action from the script from aerofs, when data will be created. When I try to create files then it reacts. Any suggestions?